# RewriteRule not matching for URL containing hash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling with an htaccess rule at the moment - my knowledge of htaccess is rather rusty.

I want to internally rewrite (ie no redirect) a URL that contains a hash from 
`http://example.com/resources/3d/35d891df36cc4f08e10915e267ff54e4/index.php` to `http://example.com/3d/resources/35d891df36cc4f08e10915e267ff54e4/` in order to work around a really crappy implementation in some legacy code. I've written the following rule to do the redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resources/3d/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/index.php$
RewriteRule /3d/resources/$1 [NC]
```

However, while the first part is matching, the second is not, and I can't see where I've gone wrong. Can anyone else point out the error?

Htaccess tester link [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=11cb774b-8b07-55e9-b133-85408f6ac7a6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close to getting this to work. So I've made two small changes to make this work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resources/3d/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/index.php$
RewriteRule ^ /3d/resources/%1? [NC]
```

Adding `^` to the rewrite rule and changing `$1` to `%1`. Your use of `$` was grabbing the resources directory again and not the query, changing this to `%1` fixes this. I've added `?` to stop any further queries from being added to the end of the URL.

Testing Link -> [Here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=ece70699-755c-5083-8173-4aeb6c9df08f)